# Run Nexus 3 with Docker in a Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, nexus

What would be the best setup to run `sonatype\nexus3` in Kubernetes that allows using the Docker repositories?

Currently I have a basic setup:

- Deployment of `sonatype\nexus3`
- Internal service exposing port 80 and 5000
- Ingress + kube-lego provides HTTPS access to the Nexus UI

How do I get around the limitation of ingress that doesn't allow more than one port?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## tl;dr

Nexus needs to be served over SSL, otherwise docker won't connect to it. This can be achieved with a k8s ingress + [kube-lego](https://github.com/jetstack/kube-lego/) for a [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) certificate. Any other real certificate will work as well. However, in order to serve both the nexus UI and the docker registry through one ingress (thus, one port) one needs a reverse proxy behind the ingress to detect the docker user agent and forward the request to the registry.

```
                                                                             --(IF user agent docker) --> [nexus service]nexus:5000 --> docker registry
                                                                             |
[nexus ingress]nexus.example.com:80/ --> [proxy service]internal-proxy:80 -->|
                                                                             |
                                                                             --(ELSE                ) --> [nexus service]nexus:80   --> nexus UI
```

---

### Start nexus server

*nexus-deployment.yaml*
This makes use of an azureFile volume, but you can use any volume. Also, the secret is not shown, for obvious reasons.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nexus
  namespace: default

spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nexus
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nexus
          image: sonatype/nexus3:3.3.1
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8081
            - containerPort: 5000
          volumeMounts:
            - name: nexus-data
              mountPath: /nexus-data
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 440m
              memory: 3.3Gi
            limits:
              cpu: 440m
              memory: 3.3Gi
      volumes:
        - name: nexus-data
          azureFile:
            secretName: azure-file-storage-secret
            shareName: nexus-data
```

It is always a good idea to add health and readiness probes, so that kubernetes can detect when the app goes down. Hitting the `index.html` page doesn't always work very well, so I'm using the REST API instead. This requires adding the Authorization header for a user with the `nx-script-*-browse` permission. Obviously you'll have to first bring the system up without probes to set up the user, then update your deployment later.

```
      readinessProbe:
        httpGet:
          path: /service/siesta/rest/v1/script
          port: 8081
          httpHeaders:
            - name: Authorization
              # The authorization token is simply the base64 encoding of the `healthprobe` user's credentials:
              # $ echo -n user:password | base64
              value: Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==
        initialDelaySeconds: 900
        timeoutSeconds: 60
      livenessProbe:
        httpGet:
          path: /service/siesta/rest/v1/script
          port: 8081
          httpHeaders:
            - name: Authorization
              value: Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==
        initialDelaySeconds: 900
        timeoutSeconds: 60
```

Because nexus can sometimes take a long time to start, I use a very generous initial delay and timeout.

*nexus-service.yaml* Expose port 80 for the UI, and port 5000 for the registry. This must correspond to the port configured for the registry through the UI.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: nexus
  name: nexus
  namespace: default
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/services/nexus

spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8081
  - name: docker
    port: 5000
    targetPort: 5000
  selector:
    app: nexus
  type: ClusterIP
```

### Start reverse proxy (nginx)

*proxy-configmap.yaml* The *nginx.conf* is added as ConfigMap data volume. This includes a rule for detecting the docker user agent. This relies on the kubernetes DNS to access the `nexus` service as upstream.

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  nginx.conf: |
    worker_processes auto;

    events {
        worker_connections 1024;
    }

    http {
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
        access_log  /dev/null;
        proxy_intercept_errors off;
        proxy_send_timeout 120;
        proxy_read_timeout 300;

        upstream nexus {
            server nexus:80;
        }

        upstream registry {
            server nexus:5000;
        }

        server {
            listen 80;
            server_name nexus.example.com;

            keepalive_timeout  5 5;
            proxy_buffering    off;

            # allow large uploads
            client_max_body_size 1G;

            location / {
            # redirect to docker registry
            if ($http_user_agent ~ docker ) {
                proxy_pass http://registry;
            }
            proxy_pass http://nexus;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto "https";
            }
        }
    }
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: internal-proxy-conf
  namespace: default
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/configmaps/internal-proxy-conf
```

*proxy-deployment.yaml*

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: internal-proxy
  namespace: default

spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        proxy: internal
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx:1.11-alpine
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          lifecycle:
            preStop:
              exec:
                command: ["/usr/sbin/nginx","-s","quit"]
          volumeMounts:
            - name: internal-proxy-conf
              mountPath: /etc/nginx/
          env:
            # This is a workaround to easily force a restart by incrementing the value (numbers must be quoted)
            # NGINX needs to be restarted for configuration changes, especially DNS changes, to be detected
            - name: RESTART_
              value: "0"
      volumes:
        - name: internal-proxy-conf
          configMap:
            name: internal-proxy-conf
            items:
              - key: nginx.conf
                path: nginx.conf
```

*proxy-service.yaml* The proxy is deliberately of type `ClusterIP` because the ingress will forward traffic to it. Port 443 is not used in this example.

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: internal-proxy
  namespace: default

spec:
  selector:
    proxy: internal
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
  type: ClusterIP
```

### Create Ingress

*nexus-ingress.yaml* This step assumes you have an nginx ingress controller. If you have a certificate you don't need an ingress and can instead expose the proxy service, but you won't have the automation benefits of kube-lego.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nexus
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"

spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - nexus.example.com
      secretName: nexus-tls
  rules:
    - host: nexus.example.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName: internal-proxy
            servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Whoa, cool. Want to turn this in to a blog post for us or even add it to the Nexus Exchange? Pop over to: http://exchange.sonatype.com/ if you are interested.

Answer (score 6):

I think this could be done just using the nginx ingress. by using a path or sub domain for you ingress.  For example:

**Service**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: nexus
  name: nexus
  namespace: default
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/services/nexus

spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8081
  - name: docker
    port: 5000
    targetPort: 5000
  selector:
    app: nexus
  type: ClusterIP
```

**Ingress**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nexus
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"

spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - nexus.example.com
        - docker.example.com
      secretName: nexus-tls
  rules:
    - host: nexus.example.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName: nexus
            servicePort: 80
    - host: docker.example.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName: nexus
            servicePort: 5000
```

Here `https://nexus.example.com` will get you to you Nexus UI and all registry functions that work over the normal HTTP port.  `https://docker.example.com:5000` will expose your docker repo. While this requires you using two different hostnames, its a little more explicit and doesn't rely on the client properly setting the user agent.  This also happens to be the strategy that the Nexus Helm chart uses, as seen here:

https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/tree/master/stable/sonatype-nexus

Comment: A more terse solution than switching on the client's user_agent. Nice.

Answer (score 5):

#### Complete Nexus Setup using Helm

This assumes you have nginx ingress with proper TLS configuration running and your cluster can handle Persistent Volume Claims:

**Install Nexus**

Install Nexus in your cluster using helm:

```
helm install stable/sonatype-nexus --name registry --namespace foo
```

Note: You can revoke the installation with this command:

```
helm del --purge registry
```

**Adjust Nexus deployment**

After installing Nexus with helm you'll find a *deployment* for Nexus. Add `containerPort: 5000` to it, right below the containterPort that is already there.

**Adjust Nexus Service**

You also need to add port `5000` to the Nexus service. Put it just below the default port:

```
- port: 5000
  targetPort: 5000
  protocol: TCP
  name: docker
```

**Example Ingress config**:

This config points `https://registry.example.com` to the Nexus UI at port `8081` and it points `https://docker.exmaple.com` to the docker service at port `5000`.

Note: In my case port `8081` was the default port that was provided in the Nexus deployment, which you edited in the step above. Adjust it, if your installation uses another port.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-com-ingress
  namespace: foo
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx

spec:
  rules:

  # Provide the docker backend that is used for docker login.
  - host: docker.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: registry-sonatype-nexus
          servicePort: 5000

  # Provide the nexus backend that is used for the UI etc.
  - host: registry.exmaple.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: registry-sonatype-nexus
          servicePort: 8081

  tls:
  - secretName: example-com-tls
    hosts:
    - registry.example.com
    - docker.example.com
```

**Configure Nexus**

You should now be able to open the Nexus UI at `https://registry.example.com`. Login with default credentials. user: `admin` pw: `admin123`.

Create a docker host repo and set `HTTP` under `Repository Connector` to `5000` and disable `Force Basic Authentication`.

**Login, tag and push an image**

You should now be able to log your docker client in to the registry using Nexus login credentials:

```
docker login docker.example.com
```

Use this pattern to tag and push an image:

```
docker tag <image>:<tag> <nexus-hostname>/<namespace>/<image>:<tag>
docker push <nexus-hostname>/<namespace>/<image>:<tag>
```

E.g:

```
docker tag myapp:1.0.0 docker.example.com/foo/myapp:1.0.0
docker push docker.example.com/foo/myapp:1.0.0
```